# Is it a bad practice (anti-pattern) to provide a module as an argument when initialising a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a implemented a `BaseScanner` inside `common/base/scanner.py` that is subclasses by `Scanner` inside `stash/scanner.py`, jira/scanner.py, etc.

Now, the problem is that `BaseScanner` needs to access the ORM models in e.g. `stash/db/models.py`, depending on where it's subclasses (in `stash`, `jira`, etc.):

```
# common package
common/base/scanner.py

# stash package
stash/scanner.py
stash/db/models.py

# jira package
jira/scanner.py
jira/db/models.py
...
```

Is it an anti-pattern to provide a module as an argument to a class when instantiating it, like I do here in `main.py`?

```
import stash, jira
...
if args.command == 'stash':
   import stash.db.models as models
   scanner = jira.Scanner(args, models, ...)
   scanner.run()
```

and then to access the different ORM models from inside `BaseScanner`, like `self.models.Scan`, `self.models.Match`, etc.?

If it's an anti-pattern, what could an alternative solution be?

Comment: I've never needed to do this, but it seems ok to me.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - thanks for your comment. Can you think of a better way of doing it?

Comment: Why not import the correct model in each scanner file?

Comment: @DeepSpace - the base class don’t know which to import